# How to control simultaneous access to multiple shared queues by multiple producers?

Tags: multithreading, producer-consumer

One way would be to lock and then check the status of first shared queue, push data if space available, or ignore if not, and then unlock.

Then check the status of second shared queue, push data if space available, or ignore if not, and then unlock.

So, on and so forth.

Here we'll be constantly locking and unlocking to see the status of a shared queue and then act accordingly.

---

**Questions:**

What are the drawbacks of this method? Of course time will be spent in locking and unlocking. Is that it?

What are the other ways to achieve the same effect without the current method's drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you are making too many locks/unlocks here. The solution is to make the same check twice:

```
check if space is available, if not, continue
lock
check if space is available AGAIN 
... go on as you did before.
```

This way you will lock if you needn't to do it only in very rare cases.

I have first seen the solution in the book "Professional Java EE Design Patterns" (Yener, Theedom)

Edit.

### About spreading the start queue numbers among threads.

Notice, that without any special organization these threads are waiting for queues only the first time. The next time the necessary timeshift will be already created by simply waiting. Of course, we can create the timeshift ourselves, spreading the start numbers among threads. And that simple spread by equal shift will be more effective that a random one.

Answer (score 2):

Lock contention is very expensive because it requires a context switch - see [the LMAX Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) for a more in-depth explanation, in particular the [performance results page](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Performance-Results); the Disruptor is a [lock-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) bounded queue that exhibits less latency than a bounded queue that uses locks.

One way to reduce lock contention is to have your producers check the queues in a different order from each other, for example instead of each producer checking Queue1, then Queue2, ... and finally QueueN, each producer would repeatedly generate a random number between [1, N] and then check Queue[`Rand(N)`].  A more complex solution would be to maintain a set of queues sorted according to their available space (e.g. in Java this would be a [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)), then have each producer remove the queue from the head of the set (i.e. the queue with the most available space that is not being simultaneously accessed by another producer), add an element, and insert the queue back into the set; a simpler solution along the same vein is to maintain an unbounded unsorted queue of queues and to have a producer remove and check the queue from the head of the queue of queues and to then insert the queue back into the tail of the queue of queues, which would ensure that only one producer is able to check a queue at any given point of time.

Another solution is to reduce and ideally eliminate the number of locks - it's difficult to write lock-free algorithms but it's also potentially very rewarding as demonstrated by the performance of LMAX's lock-free queue.  In lieu of replacing your locked bounded queues with LMAX's lock-free bounded queues, another solution is to replace your locked bounded queues with lock-free unbounded queues (e.g. Java's [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html); lock-free unbounded queues are much more likely to be in your language's standard library than lock-free bounded queues) and to place conservative lock-free guards on these queues.  For example, using Java's [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for the guards:

```
public class BoundedQueue<T> {
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private AtomicInteger bound = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final int maxSize;

    public BoundedQueue(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public T poll() {
        T retVal = queue.poll();
        if(retVal != null) {
            bound.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public boolean offer(T t) {
        if(t == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        int boundSize = bound.get();
        for(int retryCount = 0; retryCount < 3 && boundSize < maxSize; retryCount++) {
            if(bound.compareAndSet(boundSize, boundSize + 1)) {
                return queue.offer(t);
            }
            boundSize = bound.get();
        }
        return false;            
    }
}
```

`poll()` will return the element from the head of the queue, decrementing `bound` if the head element isn't null i.e. if the queue isn't empty.  `offer(T t)` attempts to increment the size of `bound` without exceeding `maxSize`, if this succeeds then it puts the element at the tail of the queue, else if this fails three times then the method returns false.  This is a conservative guard because it is possible for `offer` to fail even if the queue isn't full, e.g. if an element is removed after `boundSize = bound.get()` sets `boundSize` to `maxSize`, or if the `bound.compareAndSet(expected, newVal)` method happens to fail three times due to multiple consumers calling `poll()`.